# Cancel Button on Java

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, cancel-button

So I'm trying to make a java applet and I am trying to make a cancel button, so when it is clicked, it exits out. I keep getting an error where it says

> cannot find symbol - class MyMouseListener2 
>   button1.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener2());

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class registrations{
Button button1;
Button button2;
TextField objTextField1;
TextField objTextField2;
TextField objTextField3;
TextField objTextField4;
TextField objTextField5;   
Label label1;
Label label2;
Label label3;
Label label4;
Label label5;
Label label6;

public static void main (String args[]){
registrations r = new registrations();
}
public registrations() {
Frame f = new Frame ("Sum of Numbers");
Button button1 = new Button("Ok");
button1.setBounds(30,305,150,75);
button1.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener1());
Button button2 = new Button("Cancel");
button2.setBounds(230,305,150,75);
button1.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener2());
f.add(button1);
f.add(button2);

label1 = new Label("First Number: ");
label1.setBounds(20,75,100,25);
f.add(label1);

label2 = new Label("Last Name: ");
label2.setBounds(20,115,100,25);
f.add(label2);

label3 = new Label("Email Address: ");
label3.setBounds(20,155,100,25);
f.add(label3);

label4 = new Label("Username: ");
label4.setBounds(20,195,100,25);
f.add(label4);

label5= new Label("Password: ");
label5.setBounds(20,235,100,25);
f.add(label5);

label6 = new Label();

objTextField1 = new TextField("", 15);
objTextField1.setBounds(140,75,75,25);
objTextField2 = new TextField("",0);
objTextField2.setBounds(140,115,75,25);
objTextField3 = new TextField("",0);
objTextField3.setBounds(140,155,75,25);
objTextField4 = new TextField("",0);
objTextField4.setBounds(140,195,75,25);
objTextField5 = new TextField("",0);
objTextField5.setBounds(140,235,75,25);

f.add(label6);

f.add(label1);
f.add(label2);
f.add(label3);
f.add(label4);
f.add(label5);
f.add(objTextField1);
f.add(objTextField2);
f.add(objTextField3);
f.add(objTextField4);
f.add(objTextField5);
f.add(label6);

f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
{
    public class MyMouseListener2 extends MouseAdapter{
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }  
});
f.setSize(400,400);
f.setVisible(true);
}
    public class MyMouseListener1 extends MouseAdapter{
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){
            label6.setText("Thank you for registering!");
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong can you please help me?

Comment: 1) Use a logical & consistent code formatting style!  The code indentation is intended to help people follow the program flow. 2) Swing GUIs might have to work on different platforms, using different PLAFs, on different screen sizes and resolutions with different default settings for font size.  As such, they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of layout managers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) as well as [layout padding and borders](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556) for white space.

Comment: .. 3) Why use AWT components rather than Swing?  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon AWT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To your problem...

You are trying to create a class within an anonymous class...

```
f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public class MyMouseListener2 extends MouseAdapter {

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
});
```

This isn't going to work, besides which, you totally ignore the `WindowAdapter` anyway.  This means (even if it did work), `MyMouseListener2` would only be accessible from within the context of the `anonymous` `WindowAdapter`...

### To the solution...

Don't use a `MouseListener` for buttons, it won't take into account what would happen if the user pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> while the button was focused, instead, you want to add a `ActionListener` to the button...

```
button1.addMouseListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

This will take into account both the mouse click and keyboard events (and calling `doClick` on the button)...

Get rid of `MyMouseListener2` in the `WindowAdapter`, it makes no sense and simply won't compile anyway (yes there's away to make it work, but it makes no sense to do it this way, so you might as well get rid of it).

If you want to, you could also create a class that extends from `ActionListener` and use an instance of that instead or you could take advantage of the `Action`s API

With the `Action`s API, you could do funky things like use the [key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to register the <kbd>Escape</kbd> to trigger the same action and use the same action as a `JMenuItem` on a menu bar...

Take a closer look at...

- [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
- [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)
- [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

for more details...

Answer (score 0):

MyMouseListener1 and MyMouseListener2 are defined in the listener. They are not visible to outside of the block of code.

Here's your code fixed:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class registrations{
Button button1;
Button button2;
TextField objTextField1;
TextField objTextField2;
TextField objTextField3;
TextField objTextField4;
TextField objTextField5;   
Label label1;
Label label2;
Label label3;
Label label4;
Label label5;
Label label6;

private MouseAdapter mouseListener;

public static void main (String args[]){
registrations r = new registrations();
}
public registrations() {
    mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseClicked(e);
            System.out.println("clicked");
        }
    };
Frame f = new Frame ("Sum of Numbers");
Button button1 = new Button("Ok");
button1.setBounds(30,305,150,75);
button1.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener1());
Button button2 = new Button("Cancel");
button2.setBounds(230,305,150,75);
button1.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
f.add(button1);
f.add(button2);

label1 = new Label("First Number: ");
label1.setBounds(20,75,100,25);
f.add(label1);

label2 = new Label("Last Name: ");
label2.setBounds(20,115,100,25);
f.add(label2);

label3 = new Label("Email Address: ");
label3.setBounds(20,155,100,25);
f.add(label3);

label4 = new Label("Username: ");
label4.setBounds(20,195,100,25);
f.add(label4);

label5= new Label("Password: ");
label5.setBounds(20,235,100,25);
f.add(label5);

label6 = new Label();

objTextField1 = new TextField("", 15);
objTextField1.setBounds(140,75,75,25);
objTextField2 = new TextField("",0);
objTextField2.setBounds(140,115,75,25);
objTextField3 = new TextField("",0);
objTextField3.setBounds(140,155,75,25);
objTextField4 = new TextField("",0);
objTextField4.setBounds(140,195,75,25);
objTextField5 = new TextField("",0);
objTextField5.setBounds(140,235,75,25);

f.add(label6);

f.add(label1);
f.add(label2);
f.add(label3);
f.add(label4);
f.add(label5);
f.add(objTextField1);
f.add(objTextField2);
f.add(objTextField3);
f.add(objTextField4);
f.add(objTextField5);
f.add(label6);

f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
{
    final class MyMouseListener2 extends MouseAdapter{
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }  
});
f.setSize(400,400);
f.setVisible(true);
}
    final class MyMouseListener1 extends MouseAdapter{
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){
            label6.setText("Thank you for registering!");
        }
    }
}
```